# Using events on dynamic markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, meteor, google-maps-markers, marker

I have this init function in JavaScript:

```
inicia2 = function(){
console.log("google maps init")

     //Variables declaration
        var lat,long,
        cordenadasClientes = Clientes.find({}, {fields:{'metadata.latCliente':           1,'metadata.longCliente':                       1,'metadata.nombreCliente':1}}).fetch();

    //Getting Geolocation
       lat = Session.get('lat');
       long = Session.get('lon');

    //Map Options
       var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      styles:[{"stylers":[{"hue":"#ff1a00"},{"invert_lightness":true},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":33},{"gamma":0.5}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#2D333C"}]}],
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

   //initialize Map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa_general"),
           mapOptions);

   //Geolocation Marker
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
            map: map,
           title: 'Segun nosotros tu te encuentras Aqui!',
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        i  con:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
      });

   //Dinamyc markers and info Window
      var texto = "Dale pa ",infowindow,marker2,markers = [];
       for(var i=0;i<cordenadasClientes.length;i++){
          var latitudCliente = cordenadasClientes[i].metadata.latCliente;
          var longitudCliente = cordenadasClientes[i].metadata.longCliente;
          var nombreCliente = cordenadasClientes[i].metadata.nombreCliente;

    //dinamic marker
        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudCliente ,longitudCliente),
          map: map,
          title: nombreCliente,
         icon :'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_yellow.png',
     });

    //dinamic infoWindow
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: texto + nombreCliente
     });

   //populatin markers array
     markers.push(marker2);  
     } //closing for
// Seems like this is the problem
          google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function() {  
      infowindow.open(map,markers);
    });
 }
```

I need  `markers[i]` inside the google.maps.event.addListener, but functions are not allowed inside a loop.

The map works fine, it is creating all the markers (geo markers and client markers).

I'm rendering the map like this:

```
Template.mapaGeneral.rendered = function(){ 
     inicia2();
}
```

This is the image:

[image: map]

The yellow markers were created dynamically.

**Solution:**
Just adding an extra parameter, so each infoWindow has different content according to each client on mongo collection and using some for loop

So now the function looks like this:

```
    function myInfoWindow(marker2,map,nombreCliente){
       var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
          for(var i=0;i<cordenadasClientes.length;i++){
          infoWindow.setContent("Dale Pa " + nombreCliente);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker2);
      }});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using like this:

after `markers.push(marker2);`use `myInfoWindow(marker2,map);`
and add this function to your code:

```
function myInfoWindow(marker2,map){// this method will bind infowindow to your marker.
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'mouseover', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent("hi it's an infowindow");
    infoWindow.open(map, marker2);
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'mouseout', function() {infoWindow.close();});
}
```

Comment: Bro its working but like i say, i have an array of markers, so i need to create diferents infoWindows, i guess i need to have kinda of cursos on the array of markers

Comment: with that function create the same windows on all markers

Comment: you have to add one more parameter to the function myInfoWindow(marker2,map,content) as content and use this content in setContent(content);so it will show the given content.what i have written is to give you an idea.

Comment: yep i know actually this is how my setContent looks **infoWindow.setContent(texto + nombreCliente);** where **var texto = "some string" and var nombreCliente = metadata.nombreCliente (metadata from FSCollection)**

Comment: then what is the problem.

Comment: the same value from 2 different, but if i put the mouseOn each marker the "title" its different

Comment: i think im creating wrong my markers array or something

Comment: may be i'm not getting,are you talking about two marker on same point.

Comment: im uploading an image, but my internet is slow